# How to nearest date in the future to between today with sql (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to see the report date with the nearest future date. I want it to be a single record based on implementation id. Today 02-18-2022

```
SELECT   *
   FROM     document_reports
   WHERE    reportDate >= now() AND reportDate in 
   (SELECT MIN(reportDate) 
   FROM document_reports 
   WHERE reportDate >= NOW()
   group by implementation_id )
   
   group by implementation_id
   order by reportDate
```

You can check the tables in the below

[image: You can check the tables in the below]

Please help me? Where did I make mistake?

Comment: Why are you grouping by `implementation_id` in the outer query?  Your `SELECT` clause has no aggregations...

Comment: Because It should be single record for every implementation_id. This is what I want. When I do not write group by implementation_id , It gives two record of every implementation_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's MySQL 5.x, then I'd use a correlated sub-query, or a join on an aggregate sub-query...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  document_reports
WHERE
  reportDate = (
    SELECT MIN(reportDate)
      FROM document_reports   AS lookup
     WHERE lookup.implementation_id  = document_reports.implementation_id
       AND lookup.reportDate        >= NOW()
  )
ORDER BY
  reportDate

Or...

SELECT
  document_reports.*
FROM
(
  SELECT implementation_id, MIN(reportDate) AS minReportDate
    FROM document_reports
   WHERE reportDate >= NOW()
GROUP BY implementation_id
)
  AS lookup
INNER JOIN
  document_reports
    ON  document_reports.implementation_id = lookup.implmentation_id
    AND document_reports.reportDate        = lookup.minReportDate
ORDER BY
  document_reports.reportDate
```

If it's MySQL 8 then I'd use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY implementation_id
                           ORDER BY reportDate
                      )
                        AS rn
  FROM
    document_reports
  WHERE
    reportDate >= NOW()
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It works! .Can I get today also? This query is not working for today report.

Comment: `WHERE reportDate >= CURDATE() AND reportDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`?

Comment: It is not working :(                                                     SELECT
  *
FROM
  document_reports
WHERE
  reportDate = (
    SELECT MIN(reportDate)
      FROM document_reports   AS lookup
     WHERE lookup.implementation_id  = document_reports.implementation_id
       AND lookup.reportDate >= now() AND   reportDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) 
ORDER BY
  reportDate

Comment: `>= CURDATE()`, not `>= NOW()`. `AND lookup.reportDate <` not just `AND reportDate <`. If you have further difficulties, please open a new question, and provide sample data demonstrating your needs, errors you receive, etc.

Comment: how can I write this code with eloquent?